# What is inertial mass in quantum gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, mass, definition, quantum-gravity

In classical physics for a an object with rest mass, the following definition is adequate.

Inertial Mass ≡ (Change in Momentum)/Force.

Momentum defined according to general relativity.  In not quantized gravitational theory, this definition of inertial mass can be used to test the proposition that gravitational mass equals inertial mass. The definition that I gave does not take quantum uncertainty into account.

My question is: if in a given formulation of quantum gravity, someone were to determine whether inertial mass and gravitational mass are equal, how would they define inertial mass?

Comment: Your classical definition (*Inertial Mass ≡ (Change in Momentum)/Force*) is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As a simple non-relativistic example, the inertial mass appears in the kinetic-energy term of the Schrodinger equation. Relativistically, inertial mass appears in the Klein-Gordon equation, the Dirac equation, the Standard Model Lagrangian, etc.

So there is no problem defining what inertial mass means in quantum mechanics. It is the same as what it means in classical mechanics, which is

$$m=\sqrt{(E/c^2)^2-(\mathbf{p}/c)^2},$$

where $E$ is the energy and $\mathbf{p}$ the momentum of a free particle.

Comment: The stress energy tensor that would naturally be the source of gravitons would handle mass in exactly that way, which makes it difficult to see how an approach to quantum gravity could contain a difference between gravitational and inertial mass. I take from your answer such a discrepancy is not because there is a non-obvious meaning of inertial mass.